# Keeping inputs in activity after moving to another activity

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio. I have two activities, MainActivity and Main2Activity. There is an edit text and a button in each one. How do I keep the input in the edit text in any activity when I go to the second activity? I tried many answers but nothing worked.

Here is the code of the activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText2;
    Button button;
    String var1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("var1", var1);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        var1 = savedInstanceState.getString("var1");
        var1 = editText2.getText().toString();
        editText2.setText(var1);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Click1(View view)
    {
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
           startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Intent extras allow you to pass values (if that is what you mean by keep) via the intent. e.g. before `startActivity(i)`  and `after Intent i = .... ` add `i.putextra("et2",edittext2.getText().toString());` along with `String et2frommainactivty = getIntent.getStringEtxra("et2");` Noting that **et2** is a key and must match.

Comment: I mean when I put input in activity 1 and go to activity 2 .. And going back to activity 1 using the button , The input of activity 1 does not lost

Answer (score 0):

To carry over values from one activity to another, you need to add a line of code before `startActivity(i);`. This line of code that you need to add is:

```
i.putExtra("inputValue", String.valueOf(editText2.getText()));
```

Then in the other activity, in the onCreate() method, add this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String inputValue = intent.getStringExtra("inputValue");
editText.setText(inputValue);
```

Obviously I don't know the name of your EditText in the MainActivity2 so replace the editText with its name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not to pass value from activity to another.. I want to keep the inputs in any activity Not to be lost while moving between activity.

Comment: you can just pass the values to each activity and put the values into the edittexts before

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the existence of savedInstanceState in your onCreate function.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Check for a savedInstanceState
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        var1 = savedInstanceState.getString("var1");
        editText2.setText(var1); // Making sure that you have assigned editText2 already, of course.
    }
}
```